# What's the best way to store API secrets and encryption keys?

Tags: security

I am using environment variables to store API secrets and data encryption keys. I wonder is environment variables are the most secure way to store such data ? If hacker get into my server, can he access environment  vars ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the platform, and it is probably somewhat opinionated, but in general I think environment variables are a good way to store secrets in many scenarios.

If for example your application is vulnerable to SQL injection, local file inclusion or some other application level vulnerability, any secret stored in a database or in a file could be easily compromised. The same attack is probably not possible if environment variables are used, local file inclusion for example can't be used to retrieve environment variables.

Also using environment variables helps with version control issues, it helps to avoid checking secrets into your VCS. It may allow you to manage secrets better across environments, only allowing relevant people to be able to learn those secrets in production.

However, in case of a full compromise of your server, the attacker can also inspect environment variables of course. But if your server is compromised to that level, you lost anyway.

Examples of better ways to store secrets could be probably listed, but they are specific to the environment and technology stack you are using. For example in Azure, Key Vault could sometimes be better, in Amazon a similar facility is the Key Management Service (KMS), etc.